# Efficiently searching array of objects with multiple properties against object within value range

Tags: javascript, arrays, search, hash, binary-search

#### Preface:

Say I have a large array of objects as such (JavaScript notation used):

```
var pointsArray = [
  { 
    x0: 2.113288452, 
    x1: 5.6060203643,
    y0: 3.1333283342, 
    y1: 11.062036352,
  },
  ... // ~ 10,000,000 entries
];
```

Now, say I have generated a single entry:

```
var generatedPoints = { 
  x0: 2.1032884, 
  x1: 5.6160203,
  y0: 3.1433283, 
  y1: 11.0626134,
};
```

What I want to be able to do is, using `generatedPoints` and some value for the margin of error, `e`, is return an array of points `returnedPointsArray` that, for each property of `generatedPoints`, match the generated point within the margin of error.

So, for `returnedPointsArray`, every property is within +- `e` of the corresponding property for `generatedPoints`.

E.g., if `generatedPoints.x0 === 5.0241002`, and `e === 0.02`, every object in the `returnedPointsArray` will have an `x0` property between `5.0041002` (i.e., `x0 - e`) and `5.0441002` (i.e., `x0 + e`).

#### Problem:

So, there is an obvious solution to iterate the entire array and check if each property is between +- `e` of `generatedPoints` (worst case `O(2n)` complexity, two separate searches for `+e` and `-e`).

I know for a single value I could order the array of points and perform two binary searches for +- `e` to reduce complexity to `O(2log(n))`. But I can't figure out how/if I can to do this for multiple values.

I also considered using a hash to "reduce" the four properties to a single hash key which I could then binary search against. However, I can't figure out/not sure if it's possible if I can do this considering I'm searching for property values between a range.

### Question!

What is the fastest way to search for property values between a range of an object within an array of objects with corresponding properties of the search object?

Comment: You seem to be looking for a [k-d tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree) or [similar data structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_partitioning#Data_structures) - an array won't suffice.

Comment: I guess you could use `Math.round` as a hashing function, however the rounding would need to be in the same order of magnitude as your `e`.

Comment: Hey @Bergi, thank you very much for the comments. I thought about `Math.round` and that does seem like a good solution for the reduced hash. Could you elaborate more on k-d trees and how they're useful/their performance for this case? I'm quite new to performance programming, I'd love to know which is the better option!

Comment: I guess you have to make something like `pointsArray.filter(p => Math.abs(Math.hypot(p.x1-p.x0, p.y1-p.y0) - Math.hypot(generatedPoints.x1-generatedPoints.x0, generatedPoints.y1-generatedPoints.y0)) <= e)`. It would be wise to cache `Math.hypot(generatedPoints.x1-generatedPoints.x0, generatedPoints.y1-generatedPoints.y0)` too...